# Recursive function to read yaml files looking for a key which includes other yaml files

Tags: python, recursion, yaml

I am attempting to write a function that reads a yaml file looking for a certain key. if the key does not exist, the function should check for an '_include' key and then check that yaml file for the same key until all options are exhausted or it finds the key.

```py
import yaml
import os.path

def load_yaml_data(yaml_path):
    """Read a YAML file and return the data"""
    try:
        with open(yaml_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as yaml_file:
            yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
            return yaml_data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        return None

def find_key_in_yaml_recursive(yaml_path, key):
    print(f"opening {yaml_path}")
    yaml_data = load_yaml_data(yaml_path)
    # print(f"Yaml data : {yaml_data}")
    if yaml_data:
        if key in yaml_data:
            print(f"{key} found in {yaml_path}")
            return yaml_path
        elif '_include' in yaml_data:
            for include in yaml_data['_include']:
                include_path = os.path.expandvars(include)
                if not os.path.isabs(include_path):
                    include_path = os.path.abspath('/'.join([os.path.dirname(yaml_path), include_path]))
                return find_key_in_yaml_recursive(include_path, key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_key_in_yaml_recursive("./test.yaml", "foo"))
```

Dir structure:

```
.
|    test.yaml
└─── test
│   │    test.yaml
│   └─── deeper
│       │   test.yaml
│       │   notexist.yaml
```

./test.yaml

```yaml
---
_include:
  - "test/test.yaml"
not_foo:
  - "some data"
```

./test/test.yaml

```yaml
---
_include:
  - ./deeper/notexist.yaml
  - ./deeper/test.yaml
foop:
  - "somedata"
```

./test/deeper/notexist.yaml

```yaml
---
nothinguseful:
  - data
```

./test/deeper/test.yaml

```yaml
---
foo:
 - some data
somethingelse:
  - data
```

'foo' exists in ./test/deeper/test.yaml. In most circumstances, the function will find it and return the full ./test/deeper/test.yaml path. However, when ./test/test.yaml has an '_include' array that lists deeper/notexist.yaml before deeper/test.yaml the function returns None.
I have not done much recursive programming but i know you need a base case but i am unsure how to implement a base case in this scenario.

Comment: The base case could workout just fine as if key in yaml_path or maybe I'm not understanding something correctly but maybe you can instead store result of each iteration or at least print it instead of returning "return find_key_in_yaml_recursive(include_path, key)" to see what's going on.

Comment: removing the return does trigger the ```print(f"{key} found in {yaml_path}")``` but the return value that is passed to the print in the ```if __name__ == "__main__":``` block is still None when notexist.yaml is listed and evaluated above test.yaml

Comment: I actually see the problem, I think you want a version of BFS or DFS recursion,  or basically any search algorithm. Basically if the path goes into dir > _include > notexist.yaml there're no way for it to get out of it and go to test.yaml. i.e. append values returned by the algorithms into a list and return the list at the end then see. it's actually hard to reproduce this without the yaml files in the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
import yaml
import os.path

def load_yaml_data(yaml_path):
    """Read a YAML file and return the data"""
    try:
        with open(yaml_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as yaml_file:
            yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
            return yaml_data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        return None

def find_key_in_yaml_recursive(yaml_path, key):
    print(f"opening {yaml_path}")
    yaml_data = load_yaml_data(yaml_path)
    #print(f"Yaml data : {yaml_data}")
    if yaml_data:
        if key in yaml_data:
            print(f"{key} found in {yaml_path}")
            return yaml_path
        elif '_include' in yaml_data:
            for include in yaml_data['_include']:
                include_path = os.path.expandvars(include)
                if not os.path.isabs(include_path):
                    include_path = os.path.abspath('/'.join([os.path.dirname(yaml_path), include_path]))
                var = find_key_in_yaml_recursive(include_path, key)
                if var:
                    return var  
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_key_in_yaml_recursive("./test.yaml", "foo"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This appears to solved my issue, i will continue some more complex tests but i think this solves the issue.

Comment: @MH If the you specify the encoding of a file as UTF-8, you should open the file as binary (`open(..., 'rb')`) and not as text (`open(..., 'r')`).